# How to convert every 50 rows to columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a csv file as follows:

```
LINK   | NAME
A0     | B
A1     | B
A2     | B
A3     | B
A4     | B
A5     | B
...
A51    | C
A52    | C
A53    | C
...
```

I'm looking for a method to convert each 50 rows into columns in the following form:

```
NAME | Link 1 |  Link 2 |  Link 3 | etc
B    | A0     |  A1     |  A2     | etc
C    | A51    |  A52    |  A53    | etc
```

Anyone has a practical solution to offer using Excel, google Sheets or other software?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(A2:B; 
 "select max(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B");;999^99))); " "))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(A2:B; 
 "select max(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B");;999^99))); " "))`

Comment: Oh, it finally works, thank you very much for your help. A quick question please, how to customize the request so that it carries every 50 lines?

Comment: by having 50 B's and 50 C's etc. right now its based on B column